# Let $X \neq \emptyset$ and $B \subseteq X$. Show $\epsilon_B := \{A \subseteq X : B \subseteq A \lor B \subseteq A^C \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let $X \neq \emptyset$ and $B  \subseteq X$. Show the system $\epsilon_B := \{A \subseteq X : B \subseteq A \lor B \subseteq A^C \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$.

I've already proved the two first properties, that is:

$\sigma 1:X \in \epsilon_B$,

$\sigma 2:A \in \epsilon_B \Rightarrow A^C \in \epsilon_B$.

However, I've trouble proving $\sigma 3:$ $\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n \in \epsilon_B$ for any sequence  $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}, \ A_n \in \epsilon_B$.

I've tried considering:

If $B \subseteq A_n$ for all $n$ then $B \subseteq \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$ (this is easy).

The other case is $B \subsetneq A_{n_0}$ for $n_0 \in A_n$. But then $B \subseteq A_{n_0}^C$ by definition of $\epsilon_B$. Looking at the complement $(\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n)^C = \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n^C \subseteq A_{n_0}$ and I'm stuck. Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by: if $B\subseteq A_n$ for **some $n$** then $B\subseteq \bigcup_nA_n$.

Else $B\subseteq A_n^C$ for all $n$, hence $B\subseteq \bigcap_n A_n^C=(\bigcup_nA_n)^C$.

Comment: Thanks !, why is it my cases fail: either $B \subseteq A_n \forall n$ or there exist a non-empty set $I = \{n \in \mathbb N : B \subsetneq A_n\}$ ?

Comment: The condition "$B\subseteq A_n$ for some $n$ " is largely sufficient for the inclusion $B\subseteq \cup_n A_n$.